# Custom maintenance page

Tags: customization, maintenance

Is there a way to add a custom maintenance page from theme folder?

I have the code for the activate maintenance mode but i can't get the styling..

```
function activate_maintenance_mode() {
    if ( !(current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ||  current_user_can( 'super admin' ))) {
        wp_die(
        '<h1>Website Under Maintenance</h1><p>Hi, our Website is currently undergoing scheduled maintenance.
        Please check back very soon.<br /><strong>Sorry for the inconvenience!</strong></p>', 'Maintenance Mode');
    }
}
add_action('get_header', 'activate_maintenance_mode');
```

Thanks in advance,
Nikola.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a theme template as your maintenance page?

Answer (score 12):

When WordPress goes into maintenance mode, it adds a file named `.maintenance` to the root directory while the maintenance is being performed, then it's removed afterwards. You can write a function inside your theme's `functions.php` that checks for this file and loads a custom maintenance page from the theme.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse84987_maintenance_mode' ) ) {
    function wpse84987_maintenance_mode() {
        if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . '.maintenance' ) ) {
            include_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/maintenance.php';
            die();
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp', 'wpse84987_maintenance_mode' );
}
```

Put your maintenance content in the `maintenance.php` page inside your theme folder and you're all set to style it however you would like.

If you use the `wp_die` function, you'll get the standard white box on grey background. This way lets you style your maintenance page like you would any other theme page.

**UPDATE**: You can also do this outside the theme by adding `maintenance.php` to the `wp-content` directory (or wherever you've set `WP_CONTENT_DIR` to point to) as a drop-in plugin. When WP checks for maintenance mode from inside [`wp_maintenance()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_maintenance/) it'll look for that file and load it if present, or load its own if not. If the site isn't in maintenance mode, or is in it for more than 10 minutes, 'maintenance.php' won't load even though the site is technically still in maintenance mode. WordPress 4.6 [introduces the 'enable_maintenance_mode' filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34936), which can be (ab)used by a tool like `wp-cli` to force the check for the drop-in and would let you run a CLI command from your maintenance file.